# Setting Focus to a Control after the Loading of the DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a UserControl in WPF and it contains a variety of controls in it... The most important being the DataGrid Control. The DataGrid control is bound to an Observable Collection list. This list filled with different items based on couple of filters selected by the user. Now, once the DataGrid displays all the data. I want to set the Focus on the first (Filters) combobox on my usercontrol. Is there any way to know when the DataGrid has completely loaded??? Is there any DataTrigger I could set that i could trigger to inform me that Grid was refreshed with new list and I can set the ComboBox to focus. Basically i'm not able to set the focus to the first control on my UserControl when the data in the DataGrid has been repopulated... Please let me know if anyone knows how to resolve this issue!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to work in code behind but sometimes that is only way. This can be done in two ways according to me:

1. Use EventAggregator to raise the event from your ViewModel once you are done with your filtering logic in it. Listen to this event in view code behind and in the handler do `firstCombo.Focus()`
2. Second is bit dirty, So there must be the button or the last control after which you apply filter on your listview. In the buttonClickHandler/or any event of the last control (like selectionchange) directly do `firstCombo.Focus()`. In this case the moment you will press your button focus will move to combo.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Nit... Yes.. i agree working in the code behind is sometimes the only way. But unfortunately, both your suggestions dont work in this case. The reason being that Focus seems to be going to the control but then looks like to be returning to the datagrid when my observable collection is rendered/displayed.
I did the following, I handled the `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` and inside the attached function in the code behind i was setting `firstCombo.Focus()`. It works as long as the datagrid has elements and the vertical scrollbar is visible. When the count is zero this code will not hit.